# Replace chars with preg_replace

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Using PHP, I need to change this

`^0123456789...$`

to this

`0123456789xxx`

1. extract optional `^` on the start.
2. extract optional `$` on the end of the string.
3. replace all `.` for `x`.

Is it possible in only one ER?

Comment: Between `^` and first `.` allways there are a number sequence.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way to do this is with [`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php), no regex required:

```
$string = '^0123456789...$';
echo str_replace(array('.', '^', '$'), array('x', '', ''), $string);
```

Output:

```
0123456789xxx
```